# Effect of His-tag on enzyme activity

Tags: kinetics, catalysis, enzymes, proteins

In my biochemistry laboratory class, I designed an experiment to study the effect of a His-tag on enzyme activity. First, I measured the activity of the His-tagged enzyme. Then, I cut off the His-tag (using enterokinase) and measured the activity again.

After data analysis, I was able to calculate the $K_\mathrm{M}$ values and $k_\mathrm{cat}$ values for both enzymes. How should I interpret the data? I hypothesize that the His-tag could interfere with kinetics. But, how do I use the data to show this? Should I compare $K_\mathrm{M}$ values or $k_\mathrm{cat}$ values?

Comment: People would usually compare three numbers: $K_M$, $k_{cat}$, and $k_{cat}/K_M$.  If any of those numbers are significantly different for the wild-type enzyme compared to the His-tagged enzyme, then you could conclude that the His tag interferes, at least somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the excised-off His-tag as well as the enterokinase protease are removed from the system. 
I would use the catalytic efficiency, *i.e.* the ratio of *k<sub>cat</sub>*/*K<sub>M</sub>* as the metric to compare the results of two conditions.